# MVC: On partial page start validation from JS without postback

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

How do I start validation from the client/javascript using the MS MVC Validation library?

Using MS ASP.Net MVC, I have a page with a PartialView in a modal dialog (change password).  When the user selects 'save', I need to validate this on the client side without a full page postback.  I am able in JS to post and refresh the partialView, however I am unable to start client validation.  The MS MVC validation starts on postback (Input type='submit').   How can I start this in JS?

Validation on the full page with postback works.  Thanks,
d

Answer (score 0):

I originally posted a link to [ASP.NET MVC 2 Custom Validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) but I realized that I missed part of the question... It does appear that a few insights are present in the post titled [Combining JQuery Form Validation and Ajax Submission with ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/21/combining-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submission-with-asp.net.aspx).